# useRef in an array of ContentEditable components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, contenteditable, use-ref

I have an array of ContentEditable components that I'd like to get the value from and display it an appropriate container next to it. My struggle is a part where I think I need an array of useRef to target specific ContentEditable component as well as set the correct e.target.value to a correct inputRef.current

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bouman-bqpts?file=/src/InputList.jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle multiple states by using index:

```
const InputList = () => {
  const [finalValue, setFinalValue] = useState([]);
  const inputRef = useRef(["", "", "", "", ""]);

  const onChange = (i) => (e) => {
    inputRef.current[i] = e.target.value;
  };
  const onClick = (i) => () => {
    setFinalValue((prev) => [
      ...Object.assign(prev, { [i]: inputRef.current[i] })
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {[...Array(5)].map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Input
            key={index}
            onClick={onClick(index)}
            onChange={onChange(index)}
            html={inputRef.current[index]}
            finalValue={finalValue[index]}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-mirzakhani-5pooz?file=/src/InputList.jsx:78-762

Comment: Thanks! That's solved my headache!

I aditionally added so that, the useRef array would be dynamic in case length of Input components would change while keeping a list of inputs rather than [...Array()]

`const inputRef = useRef(new Array(inputs.length).fill(""));

useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current.length !== inputs.length) {
      inputRef.current.push(
        ...new Array(inputs.length - inputRef.current.length).fill("")
      );
    }
  }, [inputs.length]);`